# Why is PowerShell's $LastExitCode Variable Always 0 After a Failed Build with MSBuild?

Tags: powershell, msbuild

I've noticed that when MSBuild fails, the value of the $LastExitCode variable is always 0.  I'm on Windows 7, with MSBuild v4.0 and PowerShell 2.0.  This is my MSBuild scritpt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Fail">
    <Target Name="Fail">
        <Error />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

When I run:

```
msbuild.exe MyProject.csproj
```

I can see in the output that MSBuild fails, but when I check `$LastExitCode`, it has a value of 0.  Anyone know what might be going on?

I've tried setting `$(ErrorActionPreference)` to `Stop`, but that didn't work.  I re-opened a new PowerShell window, that didn't work either.

Comment: I tried your case and the $LastExitCode is 1.

Comment: Are you running any other native commands before you check that variable?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I ran into a problem recently.  It turned out some code in my profile that was updating $lastexitcode- the code was a custom prompt generator.  Try running powershell without your profile with "powershell -noprofile" to see if the problem could be code in your profile.

Consider checking the value $?
Its false if $lastexitcode is nonzero...  It works for me even when $lastexitcode did not.

Answer (score 1):

$LASTEXITCODE is for win32 executables and $? is for PS commands. What is the value of %errorlevel% when you run the msbuild.exe from cmd?

Please read http://techibee.com/powershell/what-is-lastexitcode-and-in-powershell/1847 if you want to know more about difference between these two special variables.